# Cannot compare enums in jasmine after angular migration from 6 to 7

Tags: angular, enums, angular6, karma-jasmine, angular7

I am in the process of migrating an Angular application from v6 to v7. All is well except any test that compares enums. When I run my tests, I get many errors regarding my enums like so

```
ERROR in src/.../some-thing.component.spec.ts: error TS2345: Argument of type 'PlanDuration.SixMonths' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Expected<PlanDuration.TwelveMonths>'.
```

An example of test being run looks like this:

```
export enum PlanDuration {
  SixMonths,
  TwelveMonths
}

...
    it('should toggle plan duration to six months if the event source id is the toggle duration and the event is not checked', () => {

      component.selectedPlanDuration = PlanDuration.TwelveMonths;
      component.handleToggle(event);
      expect(component.selectedPlanDuration).toBe(PlanDuration.SixMonths); // Tests cannot run because of errors here
    });
```

However, if I cast my enum to number, my tests work perfectly! This would be less than ideal to update my specs everywhere like this:

```
expect(component.selectedPlanDuration).toBe(<number> PlanDuration.SixMonths);
```

I'm unsure if I missed something in my `package.json`. I've compared a fresh angular 7 project to my own projects and the versions of angular core, typescript, jasmine and karma between them are the same.

How can I get my tests to compare enums properly? Below is my `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "7.0.0-beta.24",
    "@angular/material": "7.3.6",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "jshashes": "1.0.7",
    "lodash-es": "4.17.11",
    "request-promise-native": "1.0.5",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "timers": "0.1.1",
    "url-search-params-polyfill": "5.0.0",
    "xml2js": "0.4.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2",
    "@types/lodash-es": "4.17.1",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-stylelint": "7.0.0",
    "jasmine-data-provider": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "1.2.0",
    "karma-parallel": "0.3.0",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
    "lodash": "4.17.11",
    "moment": "2.22.2",
    "npm": "6.0.0",
    "protractor-beautiful-reporter": "1.2.5",
    "protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter": "0.5.0",
    "stylelint": "9.6.0",
    "stylelint-order": "1.0.0",
    "tslint-jasmine-noSkipOrFocus": "1.0.9"
  }
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "importHelpers": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

tsconfig.spec.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Try "export const enum ..." instead, and in your TSConfig, try setting `preserveConstEnums: true`. Enums actually are numbers unless otherwise specified, and don't need casting, but Typescript compiles funky with Enums I've found

Comment: @JonathanSchmold, can you post this as an answer? I can try your suggestion on Monday morning and if this works, I will gladly award you this bounty.

Comment: I certainly can :)

Comment: I guess this might be a problem with Karma and Jasmine. I've been seeing some and had to fallback from 4th version to 3.99

Comment: It's a bug in jasmine's type definition. Check my answer for detail and how to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Quick fix: go to `node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts`, search for `type Expected`

```
// Change this line:
// type Expected<T> = T | ObjectContaining<T> | Any | Spy;
// to:
type Expected<T> = any;
```

That's it  :)

---

For more details, read on:

I believe this is a bug in jasmine's types definition. I set up a fresh ng7 workspace and try to reproduce your problem. Here's my finding:

There are two jasmine related `.d.ts` file in the workspace:

```
// package.json
  ...
  "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
```

I'm not 100% sure how these two work together, but they are declaring **conflicting** types for same jasmine utils. For example:

```js
// jasminewd2/index.d.ts
declare namespace jasmine {
  interface Matchers<T> {
    toBe(expected: any, expectationFailOutput?: any): Promise<void>;
    ...
```

```js
// jasmine/index.d.ts
declare namespace jasmine {
  interface Matchers<T> {
    toBe(expected: Expected<T>, expectationFailOutput?: any): boolean;
```

Now the problem is in `jasmine/index.d.ts`.

This line `toBe(expected: Expected<T>)` is simply WRONG. This is a test case, certainly you are allowed to test against `any` value. Yet `Expected<T>` is declared as some complex type of no point.

The easiest way to fix it, is to manually correct it. Solution is already given at the beginning. Cheers.

Comment: A side note. I personally think ts-check a test case source file at compile time is an overkill, and should be disabled for good. Ts-check at deisgn time is fine though.

Comment: This quick-fix makes sense but how would this ever work in a production build server set-up? Maybe a better option (other than submitting a PR ) is to override that type definition and use that in the tests. Although this would still require a change in every file that is comparing enums and the OP does not want to do that.

Comment: @Nanotron *Declaration merging* should help. 
I don't have a computer around me, so cannot test it, but I guess it should work: add a `patchJasmine.d.ts` somewhere that is *included* in `tsconfig.json`, then in the file you add this: `declare namespace jasmine {  type Expected<T> = any; }`.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into issues a little while back where Angular was telling me that it could not access `MyEnumValue of undefined`. After some fiddling, I found that exporting all enums as `const`, and adding `"preserveConstEnums": true` to my tsconfig.json made it work just fine.

But enums are always numbers unless otherwise specified, and thankfully don't need casting, but Typescript's compilation of enums can be funky at times in the same way interfaces are funky.

Edit:

In your component, make sure:

```
// If you give this a default value, TypeScript will assume
// that the only "valid" type is PlanDuration.TwelveMonths
// Type evaluates to: PlanDuration | number between 0 and 1;
selectedPlanDuration: PlanDuration = PlanDuration.TwelveMonths;

// Type evaluates to: PlanDuration.TwelveMonths | 1;
selectedPlanDuration = PlanDuration.TwelveMonths
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, along with matching a tsconfig between a vanilla ng7 app and our production app, and could not get this to work. I do feel this is an issue with TS though and will continue to investigate.

Comment: try  `expect(component.selectedPlanDuration.valueOf())`

Comment: Hey actually, what type annotation did you give to component? I feel like you have it defined as something funky, and that the type assigned to `selectedPlanDuration` literally is `PlanDuration.TwelveMonths`. Typescript lets you assign a "type" to a var as a single value of a single type. `let q: 3 = 4; // error`

Comment: I've updated my answer to cover something that could be the problem, but was not provided in your question. It's likely the issue

Comment: My component has this member: `public selectedPlanDuration: PlanDuration = PlanDuration.SixMonths;`. The suggestion of `valueOf` works though, however, not ideal to fix many specs to contain this method.

Comment: Can you post your full tsconfig file?

Comment: @JonathanScmold, I have posted my tsconfig in my question now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191117/discussion-between-jonathan-schmold-and-alex-fallenstedt).

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue while implementing new tests in an Angular 7 project (without a migration from 6 to 7). If you would rather a workaround than making a change that may affect future updates to Karma/Jasmine, you can swap the comparisons around so the enum is first:

```
expect(PlanDuration.SixMonths).toBe(component.selectedPlanDuration);
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this got down voted but I got here by searching for why the Enums in my tests where throwing  errors and this method was the most plausible for me (and I'd imagine most people who come across this post) to implement.